# Check and validate JSON data string before changing view via segue (iOS App - Objective C)

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json

I'm working on an application that gets data via JSON from an mysql database. I already created a custom table using NSJSONSerialization:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.de"];
     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 }

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
      data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
 }

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData{
     [data appendData:theData];
 }

 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
     jsonContent = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
 } 


 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
     UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fehler" message:@"error" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Schließen" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [errorView show];
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
 }
```

Now I have created a login view, which should validate a user account by checking a password before the table opens. I created a textfield and a login button which got a modal link to the table view.

Now my problem: The PHP File offers an JSON String that contains the user information and I don't know how to fill the jsonContent array before the segue opens the other view. How do I tell the program to run through the connection functions to fill the jsonContent array?

I want to proof if the JSON file holds an record for the passcode. If this is not the case, the program should do an NSAlert and the segue should stop. If there is a record, the segue should be continued and I want to serve this record to the second view.

I don't understand why the first automatically view runs through all those method, while this is not the case in my new view, when I touch the login button..

```
 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
     data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
 }

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData{
     [data appendData:theData];
 }

 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
     jsonContent = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
 }

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
     UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fehler" message:@"error." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Schließen" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [errorView show];
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
 }

 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
     if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"checkLogin"]){
         NSString *passcode = [_loginText text];
         NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://url.com/file.php&appcode=%@",passcode];
         NSURL *passurl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
         NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:passurl];
         [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

         NSLog(@"%@",jsonContent);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be sending off your request when your login button is pressed and not when you trigger the segue. Because NSURLRequests are executed on another thread in the background it won't arrive at `connectionDidFinishLoading` until sometime after the segue is completed. So instead of setting up the segue to trigger automatically when the button is pressed in Interface Builder assign an action to the button where you can start the request.

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonPressed:(UIButton*)button {
    NSString *passcode = [_loginText text];
     NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://url.com/file.php&appcode=%@",passcode];
     NSURL *passurl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:passurl];
     [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    jsonContent = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    // check to see if jsonContent has what you want here and perform the segue if it does have it.
    if (...)
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"checkLogin" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I thought about something like this and already created another Button while making the segue trigger hidden :)

Comment: How can I reach the data in the jsonContent NSArray? :/ http://jsfiddle.net/reneil/Ap6FU/

Comment: 2014-06-05 00:17:37.511 [507:60b] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16546d50 seems to make problems.. please check the jsfiddle :) It would be great if you could help me with that too

Comment: jsonContent in this case is a `NSDictionary` and not an `NSArray`. So you'll want to use something like `[jsonContent objectForKey:@"error"]`.